# Set autolayout constraint inside loop

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I would like to show my app users pictures in the same way facebook does on its groups. I would like to start from an array of users_id and add the images based on the number of users that joined that group. So far I got here:

```
//this is the array of users id 
addImagesWithArray(imageName:["139","140","138"])


func addImagesWithArray(imageName:[String]){

    var imagesArray = [UIImageView]()
    // I append the imaged inside the for loop
    for (index, _) in imageName.enumerated(){
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName[index])
        imagesArray.append(imageView)
    }
    //this is easy, I add the first image on the superview center
    let firstImage = imagesArray.first
    self.containingView.addSubview(firstImage!)
    firstImage!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    firstImage!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    firstImage!.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containingView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    firstImage!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.groupNameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    firstImage!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containingView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    if imagesArray.count > 1 {
        var leftAnchor:NSLayoutConstraint?
        for i in 1 ..< imagesArray.count {
            let imageView = imagesArray[i]
            self.containingView.addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firtImage!.topAnchor).isActive = true

            if i == 1 {
                // the second image constraint is based on the first image center
                leftAnchor = imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstImage!.centerXAnchor,constant: 4)
                leftAnchor?.isActive = true
            }else{
                // THE PROBLEM IS HERE, I thought I could set the subsequent left ancors based on the position of each new UIImageViews but as you can see, the third images goes to the far left. 
                leftAnchor = imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerXAnchor,constant: 4)
                leftAnchor?.isActive = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved removing `let imageView = UIImageView()` and using the array directly. Then I used `imagesArray[i-1]` for the subsequent images.

```
   if imagesArray.count > 1 {
        var leftAnchor:NSLayoutConstraint?
        for i in 1 ..< imagesArray.count {

            self.containingView.addSubview(imagesArray[i])
            imagesArray[i].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            imagesArray[i].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            imagesArray[i].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firtImage!.topAnchor).isActive = true

            if i == 1 {
                leftAnchor = imagesArray[i].leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firtImage!.centerXAnchor,constant: 4)
            }else{

                leftAnchor = imagesArray[i].leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imagesArray[i-1].centerXAnchor,constant: 4)
            }
            leftAnchor?.isActive = true

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: use collectionView instead